Indian music video with over the top CGI
I saw an Indian music video on YouTube featuring an Indian singer riding an old red bicycle, weaving through traffic and causing an over-the-top CGI accident with multiple cars and trucks flying through the air in slow motion.
At the end, I think a Buddha statue comes to life or at least starts moving. Unfortunately, I don’t speak the language, so I can’t tell what the song was about.

It's a Hanuman statue, not Buddha.

This is Udyogam Oodipoyindi by Ranjith from the Telugu movie Maryada Ramanna.
Red bicycle, lots of accidents, terrible CGI, statue comes to life at the end.




How did you find this?

@OccasionalEnthusiast - Googling around Indian music videos with "CGI". There aren't that many of them
